# iOS app doesnt seem to interact with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

So i've set up my Parse SDK in iOS, included all the frameworks, imported `<Parse/Parse.h>` into `AppDelegate.h` and put the following in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
[Parse setApplicationId:APPLICATION_ID clientKey:CLIENT_KEY];
[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Then in the view that loads i added the following:

```
    PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Test"];
    testObject[@"boo"] = @"foo";
    [testObject saveInBackground];
```

However, it doesn't save anything onto parse and shows no errors so don't know how to go about debugging the issue. This is the very first thing you do to test if parse works so should be relatively simple.

Also the parse database has been set up previously by the person who deals with that if that is relevant.

Also i'm running the app off the simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with me was that i set the client id and app id at the end of the applicationDidLaunch method, which called the view in which i tried to save the testObject... so i was trying to save the test object before i set the IDs